# Pandas Dataframe groupby column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe df which i need to groupby Department Name column

**Input**

| Employee Name | Department Name | Subjects | Billable | Hours | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anu | CS | Java | Yes | 8 | 01-03-2021 |
| Anu | CS | Python | Yes | 9 | 02-03-2021 |
| Anu | CS | SQL | No | 6 | 03-03-2021 |
| Anu | CS | React | Yes | 5 | 03-03-2021 |
| Anu | CS | .Net | No | 8 | 04-03-2021 |
| Bala | CS | SQL | No | 5 | 01-03-2021 |
| Bala | CS | Python | Yes | 4 | 01-03-2021 |
| Bala | CS | Java | Yes | 2 | 02-03-2021 |
| Bala | CS | .Net | No | 8 | 03-03-2021 |
| Bala | CS | React | Yes | 7 | 04-03-2021 |

**Code**

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Department Name','Employee Name','Billable'],columns=['Subjects'],values='Hours',aggfunc={'Hours': np.sum})

# Resetting index
df = df.reset_index ()
list_column = df.columns

# Adding new columns and calculation
total = df.sum(axis=1)
df.insert(len(df.columns), column='Total', value=total)

available_col = len(df.columns)
Utilization_col = len(df.columns)
utilization_row = len(df.columns)

# Adding Available column
available = 168
df.insert(len(df.columns), column='Available', value=available)

# Adding Utilization column
utilization = (total / available)
df.insert(len(df.columns), column='Utilization', value=utilization)

# Filter dataframe using groupby
df1 = df.groupby(['Department Name','Employee Name'], sort=False ).sum(min_count=1)
df1['Available'] = available

# Adding Billable Utilization column and Non-billable Utilization column
df['Billable'] = np.where(df['Billable'] == 'Billable', 'Billable Utilization','Non Billable Utilization')

df2 = (df.groupby(['Employee Name', 'Billable Status'])[list_column].sum().sum(axis=1).unstack().div(available).mul(100)).round(2)

df = df1.join(df2).reset_index()
df.index = df.index

# Round the column value
df['Total'] = df['Total'].round(2)

df = df.groupby(['Department Name','Employee Name'], as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
```

### **My Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Note**:

I tried to use reset_index, but groupby function not works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684606/merge-cells-with-pandas I think this may offer a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried making the following function and I was able to get your desired output

```
def func(x): 
for i in range(1, x['Department Name'].size):
        x['Department Name'].iloc[i] = ''
return x;

df['Department Name'] = df['Department Name'].apply(str)
df = df.groupby('Department 
Name').apply(func).set_index('Department Name')
df.head()
```

**Proof**[image]

Comment: Thanks @kartik_Bhatnagar, I need to merge department name column.

Comment: Kindly help me, how to merge(groupby) Department column