# Combine rows with similar value in a column in python dataframe- like excel merge

Tags: python, pandas

this is my sample dataframe

```
data={'ColA':["A","A","B","B"],"ColB":["XYZ","PQR","XYZ","PQR"], "ColC":[4, 100, 100, 19], "ColD" : [0,0,0,0]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to do an operation similar to excel merge so that the output should look like this.
[image]

My objective is to **only combine Col A** without doing any operations on the other columns or the index. **I do not want to turn ColA into an index**. Is there an option to do this in python. I need the output for visualization and hence the need for this merge.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
df = df.set_index('ColA', append=True).swaplevel(0,1)

was taking from here:
[Merge cells with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684606/merge-cells-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the `.set_index()` method, here's an example of what you can do :

```
import pandas as pd

data={'ColA':["A","A","B","B"],"ColB":["XYZ","PQR","XYZ","PQR"], "ColC":[4, 100, 100, 19], "ColD" : [0,0,0,0]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)

df.set_index(['ColA', 'ColB'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

output:

```
           ColC  ColD
ColA ColB            
A    XYZ      4     0
     PQR    100     0
B    XYZ    100     0
     PQR     19     0
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my original post. I do not want it in the form of index. Only a regular column in a dataframe. The solution makes it into index

Comment: Im afraid that's not possible in pandas dataframes .. , you'll have to use tring manipulation.